# Does Google Analytics method Tracker.getReferer() support android app URIs?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-analytics, referrer

I want to track activity referrer information in my android application.

`setReferrer` in the Google Analytics API seems to be a suitable method ([`com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker.setReferrer`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/Tracker.html#setReferrer(java.lang.String)))

But I can not find any documentation for it.
What can I pass to it? Only web links? Or android app URIs are supported too?

like: `android-app://com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/https/www.google.com`

I get information about the referrer from:
[`android.app.Activity.getReferrer`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getReferrer())
[`android.content.Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_REFERRER)
[`android.content.Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER_NAME`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_REFERRER_NAME)

---

**Edit:**

With additional research I found some more information about referrer in Google Analytics via it's *Measurement Protocol Parameter* `dr`:
[developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#dr](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#dr)

> Specifies which referral source brought traffic to a website. This value is also used to compute the traffic source. The format of this value is a URL.

But it also does not clarify whether or not android app URIs are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Google Analytics for mobile apps does not support referrer information at all.

Only install referrer is shown. I can't find activity referrers anywhere even if I send this info.